# CISCO IOS-XR, Python3.7, Not able to run commands like 'ls' and 'df' on Cisco router

Tags: subprocess, cisco, cisco-ios, netmiko

Cisco ios-xr router using CLI:

**RP/0/RP0#show version**

Thu Nov 25 07:53:59.103 UTC

Cisco IOS XR Software, Version 6.5.32.11I

Copyright (c) 2013-2020 by Cisco Systems, Inc.

**RP/0/RP0#run**

Thu Nov 25 07:54:05.231 UTC

**[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$df**

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on

rootfs                 3966080   1332040   2412860  36% /

76892  11848320  43% /mnt/ecu/vdd

[xr-vm_node0_RP0_CPU0:~]$

Using python:
I am able to run show commands using Connecthandler .send.command:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import subprocess
Network_Device = {"host": "10.111.22.333", "username": "USER123", "password": "Pass123",     "device_type": "cisco_xr",}

Connect = ConnectHandler(**Network_Device)
Connect.enable()
version1 = "show version"
print(Connect.send_command(version1))
```

But not able to run 'df' or 'ls' commands, as not able to reach bash prompt i reach by running 'run' command on router.

I tried:

```
disk1files = subprocess.run("df", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(disk1files.stdout.decode())
```

But seems its wrong. Please suggest the right library or code I can use here.

**This is my first question here, so bear some silly questions or mistakes done in code**

Answer (score 1):

if on DF you are referring to "Don't fragment" then it is posible to send it like

```
Connect.send_command("ping 192.168.10.10 df-bit size 1600")
```

where 1600 represents MTU, and for ls commands is link command,

```
Connect.send_command("ls-active") 
Connect.send_command("ls-active-enabled")
```

but if you are referring to df and ls in linux (disk free and list files..) then you can use os module for sending commands:

```
import os
os.system("ls -l")
```

or use call from subprocess module:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

If you need to acccess cisco bash:

```
switch# configure terminal
switch(config)# feature bash-shell
switch# run?
  run         Execute/run program
  run-script  Run shell scripts

switch# run bash?
  bash  Linux-bash

switch# run bash 
bash-4.2$ whoami
admin
bash-4.2$ pwd
/bootflash/home/admin
bash-4.2$
```